# Unicode character issue with Chinese Characters

Tags: mysql, unicode, character-encoding, cjk

I have problems with inserting some Chinese characters into the mysql database. It is working on my local machine but not working in the server pc.

I don't know why please help.

Thanks!
  [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the server PC does not support UTF-8 character set. Refer: http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?39,27011,27361#msg-27361 and http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/faqs-cjk.html

Execute SHOW CREATE TABLE `table_name`; on both Local PC and Server PC. Check the Charset and collation defined on Local PC and change the same in Server PC.